# problems with jquery mobile 1.4 and android browser

Tags: android, jquery, mobile, browser

I updated my code from jqm 1.3.2 to 1.4.0. To make sure that there were no issues after the upgrade I copied the navigation buttons to a test file. Sure enough, it does not work on the mobile browser on Samsung Galaxy 3 but works fine in Chrome. It also works fine in Chrome, FF 26.0, and IE 11 on a win 7 laptop. Here is my code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>whnwh</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="p_home" data-title="when n where" data-theme="a">

        <div data-role="header"><!-- header -->
            <p />
            <img src="images/logo.png" />
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="false" data-corners="false" data-type="horizontal"><!-- navbar -->
            <a href="index.html" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline" id="home">home</a> 
            <a href="" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline" id="my">my calendar</a> 
            <a href="add.html" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline" id="add">add</a> 
            <a href="authreg.html" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline" id="sgnin">sign in</a> 
            <a href="" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline" id="sgnout">sign out</a> 
        </div>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->

    </div><!-- page p_home -->
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is how the above page looks in Galaxy browser -

[image]

and in Chrome on Galaxy as well as all browsers on laptop -

[image]

So, what can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

RD

Comment: I am also facing the same issue in samsung galaxy s4 native android browser, if anyone get any solution, please share with us.

Answer (score 0):

I guess either no one has run into this problem or no one has an answer.
I have lost a day in migrating and fixing all incompatibilities between 1.3.2 and 1.4.0.
I am frustrated, will revert back to 1.3.2 jqm and take this task on at some later time.

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone!
The following configuration was incompatible with my android galaxy 2.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

I tested jquery-1.10.2.min.js separately and it works just fine. It's only because of jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js.

Previous jquery mobile version will work which is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```